# Why is SSH working, but not git push over SSH?

Tags: git, ssh

I am truly lost as to what is happening here. I [followed this guide](https://hayley.ws/2010/12/04/getting-jekyll-running.html) to setup a git hook on my remote server (NearlyFreeSpeech.net).

However, after setting up a git remote like so:

`git remote add nfsn ssh://USERNAME@NFSNSERVER/home/private/git/REPONAME.git`

The following command hangs at the 'Enter password' prompt - after entering the password, it keeps re-prompting:

`git push nsfn master`

However, running `ssh USERNAME@NFSNSERVER` works fine as expected!

I have double, triple checked I am entering the right password! I am also certain there are no errors in the typing of `USERNAME@NFSNSERVER`.

Comment: `GIT_TRACE=1 git blah blah` might show you more info about what git is trying to do.

Comment: Set environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` as `ssh -v`, see what happened during key exchange. Did you specified a key instead of default for using Git to `USERNAME@NFSNSERVER`?

Comment: thanks @eftshift0, this showed me it was failing at a git-lfs step which is something I added. I didn't realize git-lfs only supports https and not ssh, so this must be the issue.

Comment: It may help to keep in mind that Git-LFS is separate from Git: it's a sort of add-on that separates out the large files (so that Git itself never even *sees* the large files). The LFS stuff always uses https, as you found, and uses a separate server to store the large files.

Answer (score 0):

I added GIT_TRACE=1 and that showed that it was failing at a git-lfs step which I added to my git repository. After googling, git-lfs doesn't support ssh, which is the issue.